# jquery select option should be selected based on option id

Tags: jquery

I have to create one input text box and select box. In select, option will contains some userId values are user names. User can use both text box and select box to input the data. if he/she select any username then userId should be updated in the text box. And vice-versa if user enters userId in textbox userId should be updated in text box.

First part of functionality is working fine.

> I am not getting any solution in jQuery, how to make the particular option id selected.

**Second Part**

These are dynamically created by select and input-boxes. These will be increased. I need to do for each. How can I do the same functionality for the all using jQuery.

```
    <input type="text" id="demoInput" /> 

    <select id="demoSelect" >
    <option id="0">User Name A</option>
    <option id="1">User Name B</option>
    <option id="3">User Name C</option>
    <option id="4">User Name D</option>
    <option id="5">User Name E</option>
    <option id="6">User Name F</option>  
    </select>

    $('#demoSelect').change(function(){
        //alert('event fired');
        var id = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
        //alert('id is ' +id);     
        $('#demoInput').val(id);
    });

 $('#demoInput').change(function(){
        alert('event fired');
        $('#demoSelect').children(":selected").removeAttr("selected");


        alert('id is ' +id);     
        $('#demoInput').val(id);
    });
```

I have created [`this`](http://jsfiddle.net/7GUaq/13/) JS Fiddle as well.

Answer (score 1):

You had a few things wrong

1. `option` should have an attribute `value` not `id`
2. When getting the selected value of a `select`, using jQuery use `$('#demoSelect').val()`
3. When setting the selected value of a `select`, using jQuery use `$('#demoSelect').val(newValue)`

So your select box becomes:

```
<select id="demoSelect" >
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
<option value="4">Option 4</option>
<option value="5">Option 5</option>
<option value="6">Option 6</option>  
</select>
```

And the code which fires when you change the textbox becomes:

```
$('#demoInput').change(function(){
    alert('event fired');
    $('#demoSelect').children(":selected").removeAttr("selected");

    var id= $(this).val();                       
    alert('id is ' +id);     
    $('#demoSelect').val(id);
});
```

Working branch of your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CGQ7N/

Answer (score 1):

As your `id` was not initialized and you were doing wrong bindings. Updated your `change` event to `keyup` event, because need to click outside every time to fire the events :)

You can use `$('#demoInput').get(0)` method as index starts from 0 we need to substract -1 to it?

Specially With an index specified, `.get(index)` will retrieve a single element:

```
   $('#demoInput').keyup(function(){
         alert('event fired');
        $('#demoSelect').children(":selected").removeAttr("selected");

         var id= $("#demoInput").val()
        alert('id is ' +id);     
        $('#demoSelect').get(0).selectedIndex = id-1;
    });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7GUaq/21/)**

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's not working because you are actually not updating the `#demoSelect`'s value when the `#demoInput`'s value changes.

```
$('#demoInput').change(function(){
   var value = $(this).val();
   $('#demoSelect option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
   $('#demoSelect option#' + value).attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

```
 $('#demoInput').change(function(){
        var $val = $('#demoInput').val(); //get the value of the input
        $('#demoSelect').children(":selected").removeAttr("selected"); //unselect any selected option
        $('#demoSelect').find('#'+$val).attr('selected',true); //find the option with id="<input value>" and select it
    });
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7GUaq/22/